# Select input returns undefined using axios on ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, axios, react-select

I have a select input developed with reactJS which options are the name of the categories (getting from the table categories) using nodejs and MySQL.

**My router :**

```
exports.ajouterprod = function(req, res) {
    upload(req, res, function(imageUploadErr) {
        console.log("req", req.body);
        var today = new Date();
        var produits = {
            "Nomcat": req.body.Nomcat,
            "Img": imge
        }
        console.log("Image : " + req.body.Img);
        console.log(produits)
        connection.query('INSERT INTO produits SET ?', produits, function(error, results, fields) {
            if (error) {
                console.log("error ocurred", error);
                res.send({
                    "code": 400,
                    "failed": "error ocurred"
                })
            }
            else {
                res.send({
                    "code": 200,
                    "success": "produit registered sucessfully"
                });
            }
        })
    });
};
```

**My class :**

```
class AjouterProduit extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            Nomcat: [],
            Img: "",
            FormData :"",
        };

        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);

    }
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        console.log("nextProps", nextProps);
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        axios({
            method: "get",
            url: "/app/getcat/",
            withCredentials: true,
        }).then(response => {
            if (response && response.data) {
                this.setState({
                    Nomcat: response.data
                });
            }
        }).catch(error => console.log(error));
    }
handleSubmit() {
        const formData = new FormData();

        formData.append('Nomcat', this.Nomcat);

        formData.append('Img', this.state.Img);

        axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: '/app/ajouterprod/',
            data: formData,
            withCredentials: true,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            }
        }).then(function(response) {
            this.setState({
                alert: null
            });
            this.props.history.push('/produits/listeproduits')
        }.bind(this))
    }

 handleNomcatChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            Nomcat: e.target.value
        });
    }
 handleImgChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            Img: e.target.files[0]
        });
    }
render() {
        let {Nomcat} = this.state.Nomcat;


return (<div className="animated fadeIn">
           <Row>
          <Col xs="12"  >

              <Card>
                <CardHeader>
              <h4><strong>    <i className="fa fa-cube"> </i> Ajouter un nouveau produit</strong></h4>

                </CardHeader>

                  <CardBody>
                    <Form className="form-horizontal"  method="POST" encType="multipart/form-data" >
                      <FormGroup row>
                       <Col md="3">
                    <h5>  <Label htmlFor="hf-nom"><strong>Catégorie</strong></Label></h5>
                    </Col>
                    <Col xs="12" md="9">
                      <Input type="select" name="selectcat" id="selectcat"   value={this.state.Nomcat} >
                       <option  value="" hidden>Choisissez la catégorie</option>
                       <option  value="0" ></option>

                     { this.state.Nomcat.map((cat) => <option value={cat} key={cat.Nomcat}>{cat.Nomcat}</option>)
                      }           
                      </Input>
                    </Col>
                      </FormGroup>

                      <FormGroup row>
                    <Col md="3">
                    <h5>  <Label htmlFor="file-input"><strong>Image produit</strong></Label></h5>
                    </Col>
                    <Col xs="12" md="9">
                      <Input type="file" id="file-input" name="file-input"  onChange={this.handleImgChange} />
                    </Col>
                  </FormGroup>
```

When I run it on my frontend as you can see :

When I chose the category, it's not been selected and it's still  on the   `<option  value="" hidden>Choisissez la catégorie</option>`, when I submit the form, it will be inserted in the table but the Nomcat have `undefined` value.

How can I fix that please ?

Comment: formData.append('Nomcat', this.state.Nomcat);  you missed  to add state in between this and Nomcat.

Comment: @javed when I add state and run it, I get    ` `Nomcat` = \'[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]\' `

Comment: why are you using input element as select. if possible to you please use html select element

Comment: It's still the same problem ! when I chose, it's still on `<option  value="" hidden>Choisissez la catégorie</option>`  and returns `Nomcat` = \'[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]\'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `Nomcat` first to assign whole data object inside GET call, then you are using the value of select as `value={this.state.Nomcat}` which will give you object `Nomcat` as value and not the selection you made. On top, there is actually no way to get that value as you haven't defined `onChange` anywhere on your select.
Infact, you can get that value directly without using `onChange` inside your form's onSubmit. But then again, you are not utilising the FormData( **Uncontrolled way** ) that you get. You are fetching from state( **controlled way** )

Basically you are mixing controlled and uncontrolled components and there is a lot of stuff to learn and fix there.

Read more here - https://goshakkk.name/controlled-vs-uncontrolled-inputs-react/

Then to debug the problem first, you need to be really clear if it is on front-end or backend. Isolate it!

If the server is giving correct response, then you should probably see results of GET call in network tab of Dev tools. Google if you don't know about it.

Once it's verified, then only look into your respective front-end or back-end.

**UPDATE -**

Here we go for a simple yet complete component demonstrating the functionality for select component. 
Just remember that this is a controlled way of handling things and it should be a best way to start the things off for now.

You can play around with same code here - https://codesandbox.io/s/rm130zylkp

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class FormComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      nomcat: []
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <select name="selectedNomcat" value={this.state.selectedNomcat} onChange={this.handleChange}>
          <option key={-1}> Select a value</option>
          {(this.state.nomcat || []).map((item, i) => (
            <option key={i}>{item.a}</option>
          ))}
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // API call here
    // Assume
    const data = [{ a: 1 }, { a: 2 }, { a: 3 }];
    this.setState({
      nomcat: data
    });
  }
  handleChange = e => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    this.setState({ selectedNomcat: e.target.value });
  };
  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("selectedNomcat", this.state.selectedNomcat);
    const { selectedNomcat, whateverValue} = this.state;
    const payload = {
      param1: selectedNomcat,
      param2: whateverValue,
    }
    // POST call here
    // axios.post('/address', payload).then(res => {
    //   // Whatever 
    // });
  };
}
export default FormComponent;
```

Whenever you want to use any values from onChange event handlers, simple rules are that it should get set to right state variable and then you should actually use that state to get the values of your form elements like I did in `handleSubmit`.

GETTING the value in the form of FormData() is uncontrolled way of doing things, but we are not getting into that and remove that code entirely from your component. Infact, I would recommend to use my version of code and STEP BY STEP add API calls and other form elements. Adding STEP BY STEP will help you to know, where your code broke.

**As a matter of fact avoid FormData as it has limited browser support.**

Comment: Thank you @Kushalvm, when I run my backend with Postman, it works well, but it's the problem on my front-end.

Comment: I add onChange to   `<Input type="select" name="selectcat" id="selectcat" onChange={this.handleNomcatChange}   >`   and when I run it and I chose the categorie, I get `TypeError: this.state.Nomcat.map is not a function`

Comment: @CodeLover I have updated my answer to include a basic component for select

Comment: I will try that @Kushalvm, and take a look please here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51600494/react-select-returns-object I used formData because I have upload image on my form.

Comment: No need, just go through my implementation of how I assigned value and state variables for select and you will figure out why you are getting Object instead of string.  Please accept the answer if it helped.

Comment: It's still the same issue, it returns Object.

Comment: Did you check the Sandbox link that I shared and observed what it console.logs?